# Can I use a saucepan to cook non-liquid things, like making omelets?

Tags: sauce-pan

I know that saucepans are good for cooking things in a liquid or with decent liquid content, but are they good for sauteing or making omelets, just things that don't involve little liquid?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.

BUT.

Saucepans have high walls and will make handling something like an omelet more difficult; spatulas will have a hard time getting under the omelet.

The small surface area compared to a frying pan will not make it perfect if wanting to sautée vegetables (for example); if you put too many ingredients in the pan, then it will steam instead of browning.